# How Do I Route Audio to Speaker without using AudioSessionSetProperty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

As `AudioSessionSetProperty` may become `deprecated`, I'm trying to find an code example of how to route audio to the `speaker` using other means.

Previously I did the following:

```
-(void)setSpeakerEnabled
{
    debugLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;

    AudioSessionSetProperty (
                         kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                         sizeof (audioRouteOverride),
                         &audioRouteOverride
                         );
}
```

Trying to get same result but `without call` to `AudioSessionSetProperty`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iOS 7 which is under NDA.

Comment: Wrong. You say `AudioSessionGetProperty` is deprecated, but it is available in iOS 6. It's deprecated in iOS 7. That's breaking the NDA.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, IMHO it is not the place of Stack Overflow to police NDAs.

Comment: [footnote to previous comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94488)

Comment: @ColeJohnson, I was viewing the 2012 WWDC which states it is deprecated at 13:58 Session 505 Audio Services Deprecated.  I will not discuss why I was watching it however.

Comment: @Jim hmm. Well, my mistake then. I looked up the method on ADC (iOS 6 docs) and it doesn't say it's deprecated as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

On each release of iOS, more of the audioSession properties are migrated to AVFoundation, so you should use those in preference whenever available.

Since iOS 6 `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute` is represented in AVAudioSession by the method

```
- (BOOL)overrideOutputAudioPort:error:
```

Available values are `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone` and `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker`

Here is an example audio session configured entirely via AVFoundation:

```
 - (void)configureAVAudioSession
{
   // Get your app's audioSession singleton object
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    // Error handling
    BOOL success;
    NSError *error;

    // set the audioSession category. 
    // Needs to be Record or PlayAndRecord to use audioRouteOverride:  

    success = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                             error:&error];

   if (!success) {
       NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setting category:%@",error);
   }

    // Set the audioSession override
    success = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                                          error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error overrideOutputAudioPort:%@",error);
    }

    // Activate the audio session
    success = [session setActive:YES error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error activating: %@",error);
    }
    else {
         NSLog(@"AudioSession active");
    }

}
```

*UPDATE*

Since iOS 7.0, the Audio Session Services C API is now fully deprecated in favour of AVAudioSession.

*UPDATE 2*

```
- (BOOL)overrideOutputAudioPort:error:
```

is a method, not a property, and it sets an underlying *write-only* UInt32 value. You can't get the current value, and you should treat the method as setting a temporary state. If the audio route changes or is interrupted, the property resets to its default (`AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone`). You can get interruption notifications via `AVAudioSessionDelegate`.

Comment: How would this work for kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput in iOS 7 ?

Comment: @SjoerdPerfors -  You would use the AVAudioSession method `- (BOOL)setCategory:(NSString *)category withOptions:(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions)options error:(NSError **)outError` with `category` as  `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` or `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` and `options` as `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth`

Comment: Thanks Foundry but that is not the same because that would allow A2DP bluetooth only. And this wouldn't force using it either. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134912/how-to-route-to-kaudiosessionproperty-overridecategoryenablebluetoothinput-witho

Comment: not work for me! my code: AVAudioSessionPortOverride port = (onOff ? AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker : AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone);
    success = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:port
                                         error:&error];

Comment: @hungbm06 - perhaps you can make a new question showing more of your code... if it's returning an error, show the error

Comment: How to get current value of overrideOutputAudioPort?

Comment: If anyone else is wondering why this doesn't work for them. You need to call it immediately before playing something. So `[[AVAudioSession] sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&overrideError]; [_player play];`

Comment: @foundry, even if my app is only playing back a buffer for live audio synthesis will audioSession category still have to be set to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord to use audioRouteOverride ? why not AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback ?

Comment: @Greg: Yes - because Apple says so. The  `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker` option only works when the audioSession is set to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`. Documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AVAudioSessionPortOverride)

Comment: @foundry, I eventually got audio synthesis working again once I added AVFoundation.framework.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSError *error;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker 
                                                   error:&error];    
if(error)
{ 
    NSLog(@"Error: AudioSession cannot use speakers");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .spokenAudio, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("error.")
    }
```

// paste this code in your viewLoad region

Answer (score 1):

Foundry’s solution together with [this blog](https://github.com/software-mariodiana/AudioBufferPlayer/wiki/Replacing-C-functions-deprecated-in-iOS-7) by Mario Diana has also allowed me to upgrade audio session set up code deprecated in iOS 7. My old code was based on 
[*AudioBufferPlayer* by Matthijs Hollemans](https://github.com/hollance/AudioBufferPlayer).
 Remember to add the AVFoundation.framework.