# How can I obtain the native (hardware-supported) audio sampling rates in order to avoid internal sample rate conversion?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audio-recording

Can anybody point me to documentation stating the native sampling rates on the different iPhone versions in order to avoid `core-audio` internal sampling rate conversion?

**Edit:**
Otherwise, can you please point me to a source code example of how can I get those values programmatically?

**Edit:**
This [Apple document (page 26)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/musicaudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioOverview.pdf) refers to a Canonical audio format, but only makes mention of sample type (PCM) and bit depth (16-bit). It doesn't mention any native sampling rates supported directly by the capture hardware. Those are the values I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not asking for a recommended setting based on a preference, I'm asking for a known setting that will avoid a sample-rate conversion layer being added automatically by core-audio.  Please reconsider removing the on-hold status.

Comment: I suggest you reword your question (or rethink your approach)  slightly ... you need to know how to obtain - in code - the hardware sample rate for a device. Core Audio can provide you with the information you are after. If you can get this question re-opened I can answer it for you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is find a way to detect the hardware sample rate, and use whatever you find in your subsequent code.

There is an audio session property which will give you this: CurrentHardwareSampleRate

```
- (void) logSampleRate {
    Float64 sampleRate;
    UInt32 srSize = sizeof (sampleRate);
    OSStatus error = 
         AudioSessionGetProperty(
         kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareSampleRate,
         &srSize,
         &sampleRate);
    if (error == noErr) {
        NSLog (@"CurrentHardwareSampleRate = %f", sampleRate);
    }
}
```

iPhone 4S and iPhone 5S report hardwareSampleRate = 44100.000000 but others devices may (will) differ...

**edit**

While answering the question and reading the latest docs, I see that `CurrentHardwareSampleRate` is deprecated in iOS6. And really, I should have know better, given [my own advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808124/1375695).

So here is the thing:

1 - don't use this antiquated and deprecated C interface, use the `AVAudioSession` API

2 - don't use `HardwareSampleRate`, use `sampleRate`.

This raises the suspicion that Apple wants to distance us (even) further from the metal. But we should rest assured. While the docs for `sampleRate` only offer

> The audio sample rate, in hertz, that is currently in effect. (read-only)

notably omitting the word `hardware`, we also have this method:

```
- (BOOL)setPreferredSampleRate:(double)sampleRate error:(NSError **)outError
```

where *sampleRate* is described adequately as

> The hardware sample rate you want to use. The available range for hardware sample rate is device dependent. It typically ranges from 8,000 through 48,000 hertz.

It seems that the way we are supposed to use this, is to set our *preferred* rate, from which the device will set an (the?) *actual* rate which presumably will be as near to the preferred as feasible, based on the hardware. So once you have set your preferred rate, you can check the value of the `sampleRate` (as opposed to `preferredSampleRate`) property, to discover the actual sample rate that will be used. This is - we hope - hardware sampling.

Here is the modern way...

```
- (void) logAudioFormatAV {
    AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL success;
    NSError* error = nil;
    double preferredSampleRate = 48000;
    success  = [session setPreferredSampleRate:preferredSampleRate error:&error];
    if (success) {
        NSLog (@"session.sampleRate = %f", session.sampleRate);
    } else {
        NSLog (@"error setting sample rate %@", error);
    }
}
```

I have tried this with various preferred sample rates on the 4S and 5S and always get back 44100. So this seems to be doing the right thing, and reporting back the *actual* *hardware* sample rate. But this deserves wider testing for greater certainty.

I'd like to also point you in the direction of Chris Adamson's excellent book *Learning Core Audio*, which touches on this subject in Chapter 10, *Core Audio on iOS*.

Comment: Great answer!  I agree with your opinion that Apple seems to be pushing for a greater distance from the metal. At least, with the reduced number of device versions it is much better than with Android, where the audio stack support is so fragmented it is scary!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried this on both an iPod 4g and an iPhone 5, and found different results from yours.  

I found that session.sampleRate matched the value of the preferred sample rate as long as it were one of a set of typical values (48000, 44100, 32000, 24000); if I set it to something else (e.g. 44101), the actual rate would be the next highest one (e.g. 48000).  The new value of session.sampleRate would be set only after a call to [session setActive:YES].  Otherwise, it just retained the value from the previous run of the app.

So I'm not sure I'm convinced that 44100 is the hardware rate...

Comment: @foundry, interesting. I tried this and found that preferred sample rates over 48000 returned an actual sample rate of 48000 while for preferred rates between 44100 and 47999, the value returned was 44100. For values below 44099 returned a value of 32000. Perhaps you tell me if I've asked the wrong question with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692276/could-nan-be-causing-the-occasional-crash-in-this-core-audio-ios-app